# ifttt "Maker" Recipe: Optional Parameters are blank?

Tags: python, http, ifttt

I am using the following Python Script to trigger a 'Maker' event on 'ifttt' like this:

```
import requests
from main import get_ifttt

def trigger_event(  event, key, json_data={} ):
    ca_certs = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"  
    url="https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/%s/with/key/%s"%(event, key)
    r=requests.post( url, data=json_data, verify=ca_certs )
    assert(r.status_code==200)

if __name__=='__main__':
    trigger_event( 'calendar', get_ifttt(), "{ 'Value1': 'something' }" )
```

The ifttt Recipe creates a google calendar entry: using the text as follows:

```
{{OccurredAt}} "{{EventName}}" occurred on the Maker Channel : Value1: "{{Value1}}"
```

The Calendar event is created correctly ; but the 'Value1' string is blank? So the entry looks like this:

`"calendar" occurred on the Maker Channel : Value1: "`"

This also happens if I switch to a 'Notify' event as well ?

I have also tried using a 'curl' commandline with '?Value=xxx' appended; this also doesn't work.

I have tried using 'Value1' and 'value1': but same result.

What am I doing wrong here ?

(The code makes a call to a method called 'get_ifttt' : this just returns my secret API key).

Answer (score 4):

You can send 'value1' string by specifying Content-Type.

```python
r=requests.post( url, data=json_data, verify=ca_certs, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'} )
```

Also you should use 'value1' instead of 'Value1'.

```python
trigger_event( 'calendar', get_ifttt(), "{ 'value1': 'something' }" )
```